# How to set xticks for a pandas plot from a list of labels?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that I am plotting. The x-axis comes from `df['date']`. I would like the plot to show xticks only for dates in a list `good_dates`. How do I accomplish this?

```
df.plot(kind='bar', xticks=good_dates)
```

does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: `xticks=df['date'].where(df['date'].isin(good_dates), '')`

Comment: I'm getting a `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'` error. Possibly because `df['date']` contains datetime objects?